# Can I stop a specific flask router?

Tags: python, flask

my project use angular + python flask

(1) 
Is it possible to give each router called a unique id ?

(2) if a flask router processing is too long, 
is it possible to stop this router without stopping the flask when i click some button on the web??

i need to stop only this router.

Comment: Just to clarify, by router you mean route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will raise the exception from server side:

```py
import requests
timeoutSeconds = 1
try:
    res = requests.get(<url>, timeout=timeoutSeconds)
except:
    print("Timeout")
```

Answer (score 0):

(2) You can respond with 504 timeout gateway.